# How to setup Nightwatch.js with Mocha to use chai assertions?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to setup Nightwatch with Mocha. I don't want to use theirs assertions. How can I use chai assertions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-nightwatch) for nightwatch:

```
npm install chai-nightwatch
```

Comment: So is it as simple as installing `chai-nightwatch` and then writing assertions?
The documentation is a bit terse on any configuration needed (if any) and I can't imagine it instinctively detects that library and applies it.